# How Does an Angular form element have a list of child input type elements on it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am curious as to how angular adds child form elements to an actual form element.  I know that if an input (input, textarea, select) has a name it will be added to the form controller.  However, it also appears that it is added to the form element itself in an indexed position (see image).

[image]

I have trawled the angular source code and cannot find how and where a control is added to the form element.

Is this a browser thing to do with the form and/or how come only inputs (input, textarea, select) and button elements are added and not div, etc etc?

The reason being is that you can iterate over these elements using the below code however it is not adding some custom elements (created via directives) I have.  So they are not included in the iteration although they are present on the formControl (via their name property).

```
angular.forEach(frmElement[0], function (ctrlElement) {
       var controller, isValid;
       ctrlElement = angular.element(ctrlElement);
       controller = ctrlElement.controller('ngModel');

       // do something to the control...
});
```

Any information would be really good.

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: have you check ngForm? docs says form directive is an alias.

Comment: Yes it doesn't appear to be adding any child elements to the actual form element.  When an element has an ngModel attribute and it has a parent form controller it calls $addControl on the form controller but this only adds it to the form controller but not the form element.

Comment: interesting... i should check on that when i get home. thanks.

Comment: I don't think this actually ha anything to do with angular see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection